# Prototype. Restrict input to numbers

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have multiple inputs to which i am attaching event listener that listens to what key was pressed, tests it with regular expression and returns true if number and false if other charachter. The problem is that input is accepting letters even if my test function returns false.

```
$$(".number").each(function (element) {
  return $(element).observe("keypress", function (event) {
    return /[\d\s]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
  });
});
```

Example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yoxesisahi/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: Don't test the keyCode, look at the actual value. What about characters that are entered without pressing keys?

Comment: @RobG, you mean paste? I think that i'll make another function to validate it and combine them together.

Comment: Or drag and drop. If you test the value, then you don't need to also test the key that was pressed. The point is that you don't care what the value is until you use it, say when a form is submitted. It's also much more user friendly to just advise the user of the error (say a friendly screen tip) and let them fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using prototypeJS, which as far as I know doesn't allow to use `return false` to cancel event propagation and default behavior (As jQuery does). Though it has `Event.stop(event)` method

```
$$(".number").each(function (element) {
    return $(element).observe("keypress", function (event) {
        var result = /[\d\s]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));

        if (!result) {
            Event.stop(event);
        }
    });
});
```

[Event.stop(event)](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/stop/)

Comment: Yeap, was doing it jQuery way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by testing the value on keyup, then removing whatever was entered if it doesn't match your desired pattern:

```
$$(".number").each(function (element) {
  return $(element).observe("keyup", function (event) {
    var val = this.value

    if(!/[\d\s]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))){
      this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What if the character wasn't added at the end of the string?

Comment: "Better" is relative. It prevents any keypress that isn't a number or whitespace, including the use of cursor keys, backspace, delete, etc. Users might consider that annoying.

Comment: I'm never a fan of these solutions, per se. I would prefer to see a helpful error message instead of having my key press blocked.

Comment: I think the question was about preventing default event behavior in prototypeJS, not a complete logic which of course has to be developed in future.